# Why isn't my php script working?

Tags: php, forms, html, web

EDIT: Apparently I have to pay to register another domain on their site to have email capabilities. Sorry for the wasted time, and thanks for the code fixes.

I don't have any experience with php. I am just starting to figure it out. I am trying to get my form to send the entered information to my email. I set an else tag but that is all that happens. If you see any errors please let me know. I really want this to work. See for yourself: [Website](http://organizationxiii.co.nf/feedback.html) The codes are:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<label for="comment_author" class="required">Your Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="email" class="required">Your Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2"   required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="comment" id="comment" class="required">Your Message</label><br/>

<textarea name="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4"  required="required"></textarea><br/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
<input id="send" name="send" type="hidden" value="1" />

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['comment'];
    $from = 'From: '. $email; 
    $to = 'powersjesse@yahoo.com'; 
    $subject = 'WEBSITE';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['send'] == "1") { 
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }}
?>
```

I get `Something went wrong, go back and try again!` when I'm trying to submit the form.
**Updated code.**

Comment: well because I have the else tag it just defaults and shows 'Something went wrong...'

Comment: I edited your question and added the output after going to your website and trying to submit the form.

Comment: edited my answer; your mail() call's parameters are wrong, specifically $body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code:

```
   if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {               
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from))
        { 
           echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        }
        else
        { 
           echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
   }
```

Getting the output of:

> Something went wrong, go back and try again!

Means that something went wrong with the `mail()` function, it returned `false` , otherwise we would see the `Your message has been sent!` message.

The problem with the `mail()` function is that it doesn't show any errors or warning , it just returns `false`.

**How to locate the problem?**

Try writing something like:

```
    if(mail("your.working.email@gmail.com" , "A subject for example" , "the content of this email","From: no-reply@yourdomain.com"))
     echo "We are good";
    else
     echo "Something not workin";
```

If it works , check out the value of any of your posted variables right after declaring them.

```
   echo $name;
   echo $email;
   echo $message;
```

Make sure that those variables are not empty and that the `$email` variable contains a legal and validated email address.

If the basic `mail` usage didn't work - it's something related to your `php settings` (`php.ini`) or a limitation by your server (contact your hosting company).

**EDIT1:** About your html form , the `type` attribute of the `input fields` should be `text` and not `name` or `email`.

Instead of `<input type="email"...`
Write `<input type="text"...`

Comment: so how would I test this? new temporary php and link it to my submit button?

Comment: Have a new php file only with the `mail` function (as I wrote) , then follow the instructions and share with us the results.

Comment: I made the php file but what do I do with it? link it to my submit button on my page?

Comment: No , just upload it and run it. For instance , `bla.php` - visit `yourdomain.com/path/to/bla.php`.
Write here what's the output of this url.

Comment: Ok. Sent me to a blank page with no email. So... Server limitations? -_-

Comment: I've updated my answer , check out the new code and paste in the same file , upload it again and run it - now what you see?

Comment: Ok , that's really weird , try to contact your hosting company.

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
```

rather than method="request"

edited to add
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

edited (in response to edited question code...) to add http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

your mail() parameters are in the wrong order; should be $to, $subject, $message [, $additional_headers, etc.]

Comment: And then use `$_POST['comment']` etc to access the form values!

Comment: good spot @nickhar; just saw the error in the form, didn't look that closely at the php...

Comment: Ok. It still gives me the same message though.

Comment: did you change the     $_REQUEST['etc...'] to     $_POST like nickhar suggested?

Comment: @PedrodelSol , the order of the parameters are fine as far as I'm concern.

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="get" id="commentform">

<label for="comment_author" class="required">Your Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="email" class="required">Your Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2"   required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="comment" id="comment" class="required">Your Message</label><br/>

<textarea name="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4"  required="required"></textarea><br/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />

</form>
```

method must be get/post

Answer (score 3):

Your field "submit" is a HTML button to submit the form and will not be added to the form. Add another input field which is not visible:

```
<input id="send" name="send" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

and access the field in PHP with:

```
if ($_REQUEST['send'] == "1") {
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: ok I added that. The second one replaces if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {

Comment: And for sure, not $_REQUEST but $_POST is the right command :)

Answer (score 1):

the `name` of the textarea is `comment` and you're using it as `message` in this line,

```
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
```

Needs to be,

```
 $message = $_REQUEST['comment'];
```

Also, the method of the form submission, needs to be `POST` like this,

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
```

Answer (score 1):

please change form as follows

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
```

In the form you can use only get/post

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<label for="comment_author" class="required">Your Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="email" class="required">Your Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2"    required="required"><br/><br/>

<label for="comment" id="comment" class="required">Your Message</label><br/>

<textarea name="comment" rows="10" tabindex="4"  required="required"></textarea><br/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
```

and in your post page..

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: '. $email; 
$to = 'powersjesse@yahoo.com'; 
$subject = 'WEBSITE';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
//$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

-> Use ***POST*** instead of ***REQUEST***

-> **comment** chaged to **message**

**HTML**

```
<form action="post_comment.php" method="post" id="commentform">
<label for="comment_author" class="required">Your Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" required="required"><br/><br/>
<label for="email" class="required">Your Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2"  required="required"><br/><br/>
<label for="comment" id="comment" class="required">Your Message</label><br/>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" tabindex="4"  required="required"></textarea><br/>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: '. $email; 
    $to = 'powersjesse@yahoo.com'; 
    $subject = 'WEBSITE';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {               
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }}
?>
```